# i'm not sure why my ascii art isn't working? I've tried modifying it a bunch but it just keeps saying i'm missing a ')'

Tags: python, ascii

i'm trying to make ascii art show in my program but it jsut will not work. I am clueless as to why it will not print and it's really annoying

```
def catmeowmeow(): 
    print("________________________")
    print("|                       ‘\ ")
    print("|            _ |\_       |")
    print("|             \` ..\     |")
    print("|        __,.-"    Y     |")
    print("|______ ."        )______,")
    print("|  _    /   ,    \/\_     \ ")
    print("| ((____|    )_-\ \_-`     |")
    print("|  `-----'`-----` `--`     |")
    print("|                          |")
    print("|  ________________________/")
    print("|                          \ ")
    print("|                           |")
catmeowmeow()
```

Comment: You have several unescaped `"` in strings _delimited by `"`_.

Comment: Try putting the letter r in front of every string. Otherwise the `\`will be interpreted as part of a _special character_. For example `\t` stands for "tab" and `\n` stands for newline

Comment: Oh yeah and of course if your ascii-art contains a `"` you can't then also enclose the string in a `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a quote inside a string literal (e.g. `"this is a string literal"`) you need to escape it using `\` or use different quotes around the strings otherwise python thinks you ended the string in the middle.

These lines are the problem lines:

```
...
print("|        __,.-"    Y     |")
print("|______ ."        )______,")
...
```

There is a double quote inside the string which confuses python. Either replace them with `\"` or change the outside quotes to single quotes `'`

[A more complete explanation can be found here](https://www.codespeedy.com/escape-quotes-from-string-in-python/)